# why do bash behave differently for script from stdin?

Tags: bash, ssh

This is my script, test.sh

```
if ssh myhost true; then
  echo 1
fi
echo 2
```

p.s. I have setup ssh key for myhost, so it won't ask password.

If I run it via bash, it will output two lines

```
$ bash test.sh
1
2
```

However, if I redirect the script to bash's stdin, it only output one line

```
$ bash < test.sh
1
```

Why do bash behave differently? Is this a bug of bash or a magic feature?

I have tried bash 4.3 and 4.4.

p.s. If I replace `ssh myhost true` with `true`, the script will always output two lines.

Comment: If you add -f to the ssh command, does it run both again?  My test seems to run fine after that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: there's an important difference between having bash read commands from a file, and having bash take *all* input from a file.

`ssh` tends to read all available input from standard input, and send it over the connection to the remote computer. When you run `bash test.sh`, the shell reads commands from test.sh, but standard input is still your terminal; ssh will send anything you've typed ahead to the `true` command (which will ignore it). When you run `bash < test.sh`, standard input is set to the script, so both bash and the commands it runs read from that. bash reads the `if` block, then executes it; ssh reads the rest of the script (the `echo 2` command), and sends it to the remote `true`, which ignores it. bash then finds that it's at the end of its input, so it exits.