# Remote Execution of a Shell Script that Takes a Local File as an Input Parameter

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, openssh, bash-scripting

Using Linux, bash, and OpenSSH, I can execute a shell script on a remote host in at least three ways:

```
# Method 1: Script is never stored on the remote host
ssh <username>@<hostname> 'bash -s' < myShellScript

# Method 2: Script is permanently stored on the remote host
ssh <username>@<hostname> 'myShellScript'

# Method 3: Copy script to the remote host, execute it, and delete it
scp myShellScript <username>@<hostname>:~
ssh <username>@<hostname> 'myShellScript; rm -f myShellScript'
```

I prefer method 1 to method 2 because it prevents the proliferation of copies of the script and the associated maintenance headaches.

I prefer method 1 to method 3 because it is faster and generally "cleaner" than copying and deleting the script.

But there's a problem I need to get around if I am to succeed in my goal of
sticking with method 1. **myShellScript** is of this form:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Do stuff...
myProgram input myProgramInputFile
# Do more stuff...
```

Here, **myProgram** is a standard utility that is available on all remote hosts I might want to interact with. However, **myProgramInputFile** is a regular file that exists only on my local machine. It does not exist on any of the remote hosts.

I'd like to be able to "bundle up" **myShellScript** and **myProgramInputFile** into one nice "package" that gets executed on the remote host via SSH without explicitly storing anything on the remote file system, either permanently or temporarily. Is this possible?

Comment: Do you have the ability to share files out via, say, NFS or something like that?

Comment: See [this question](https://superuser.com/q/1194343/432690). Your *Method 1* may behave against your expectations if `myShellScript` does certain "stuff". Know the pitfalls if you keep using this method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would rather copy at least `myProgramInputFile` (*Method 3* alike); I think it would be more robust. There is, however, a way to make it work with the sole *Method 1*.

---

---

#### My approach

I advise you to make a (local) script that copies the appropriate file to the remote side, triggers execution and cleans afterwards.

We will need three local files: `myLocalScript` (executable), `myRemoteScript` and `myProgramInputFile`.

The content of `myLocalScript`:

```
#!/bin/bash

# step 1: storing command line arguments to meaningful names
ssh_command="ssh $1"
script="$2"
input="$3"

# step 2: creating remote temporary file
remote_input=$($ssh_command 'mktemp')

# step 3: copying the content of local input file to the remote temporary file
cat "$input" | $ssh_command "cat > \"$remote_input\""

# step 4: sourcing the script to the remote side
$ssh_command "input=\"$remote_input\" bash -s" < "$script"

# step 5: removing the remote temporary file
$ssh_command "rm \"$remote_input\""
```

`myRemoteScript` will look like this:

```
# shebang is not needed, this script will effectively be sourced

# Do stuff…
myProgram input "$input"
# Do more stuff…
```

The files `myProgramInputFile` (local) and `myProgram` (remote) will stay the way they are in your current setup.

**Local usage:**

```
./myLocalScript <username>@<hostname> myRemoteScript myProgramInputFile
```

Technical notes and explanations:

- In *step 2* `mktemp` creates a file in a temporary directory on the remote machine. We don't want to use `mktemp -u` to avoid the situation when somebody else actually creates a file with the same name between our *step 2* and *step 3*.
- In *step 3* we could use `scp` if we used `mktemp -u`. The remote temporary file already exists so we use `cat` to write to it.
- In *step 4* `myRemoteScript` needs to know the path to the temporary file in the remote machine context. That's why we pass our local `$remote_input` as `input` variable to the remote `bash`. This way when `myRemoteScript` is fed to the said `bash`, the `$input` in it indicates the temporary file path.
- If we break the remote `bash` (say, with single <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd>) then `myLocalScript` will advance to *step 5* and do the cleaning anyway. This is the reason why the cleaning is not at the end of `myRemoteScript`, although it could be.

---

---

#### Sole *Method 1* approach

Thanks to *[Here Documents](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#Here-Documents)* you can embed `myProgramInputFile` into `myShellScript`.

This will be easy **if `myProgramInputFile` is a text file and `myProgram` can read `stdin`** (maybe with `myProgram input -` syntax? or maybe when `input` is omitted?)

`myShellScript` will look like this:

```
# shebang is not needed, this script will effectively be sourced

# Do stuff…

myProgram input - <<"EOF"
The content of myProgramInputFile is pasted here,
it continues here
and here,
and so on.
EOF

# Do more stuff…
```

**Then we will run it as in *Method 1*:**

```
ssh <username>@<hostname> 'bash -s' < myShellScript
```

---

**If `myProgram` cannot read `stdin`** but the remote system allows you to use `/proc/self/` then we should write the crucial line in `myShellScript` like this:

```
myProgram input /proc/self/fd/0 <<"EOF"
```

---

**If `myProgramInputFile` is more than text** then we should encode it locally (see `uuencode`, `base64`) and decode on the remote side. We should also check if there's no `EOF` line in the encoded text, change the here document delimiter if so. Note that `base64` doesn't use `_` so `E_O_F` is perfectly safe in this case (but maybe not with `uuencode`, I don't know).

---

As a **proof of concept** I gzipped the Super User favicon, encoded it with `base64` and embedded in the script. I chose to demonstrate `/proc/self/fd/0` approach with `cp` but it might be `cat > ~/SUfavicon.ico` as well; or better `gzip -cd > ~/SUfavicon.ico` earlier in the pipe.

And of course in your case there would be `myProgram` instead of `cp`.

Note in this case `{}` are important, they make the here document be directed to `base64 -d`.

```
# shebang is not needed, this script will effectively be sourced

{ base64 -d | gzip -cd | cp /proc/self/fd/0 ~/SUfavicon.ico ; } <<"E_O_F"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E_O_F
```

Run it as before:

```
ssh <username>@<hostname> 'bash -s' < myShellScript
```

Then you will find `~/SUfavicon.ico` on the remote machine.

Comment: Thank you so much for such a thoroughly and clearly explained proposal! I will look it over closely later this morning.